# Cards.dll in Windows 7

Tags: api, windows-7

In older windows we had a library called cards.dll that MS used for UI in card games. It looks like they are now using something different for it. Do anyone know how Microsoft paint cards in new Windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I opened the cards.dll from 32-bit Windows XP and the file contains bitmap resources with the cards. This DLL is not present on Windows 7 (64-bit). I opened the .exe in a resource editor and did not find any bitmap references which is something I'd normally have expected.

I then opened the executable with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out if there were any additional references to the equivalent of cards.dll and there were none. There was a reference to DirectX so I suspect that the cards are being drawn using that API, and are perhaps encoded in something other than a bitmap. [Process Explorer's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) thread view also suggest DirectX is being used.